# How can I say "away at lunch" (e.g. on a sign)?

Tags: expressions, phrases

How can I say "away at lunch" (e.g. on a sign)?

I thought I might be able to just write 「昼食中」 - is that correct?

Comment: Related: [Closed: 休〜 vs. 閉〜](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41845/78)

Comment: What kind of sign are you talking about?  Like a sign you leave on your desk for your co-workers to see when you're out to lunch?  Or like a sign that a business hangs in their window when they are shut down during lunch?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted specifically to say you're away on lunch, you could say **"食事中"**, but that sign is not very common, even if it literally translates to "during eating."

If what you wanted is a way to write a sign to put on your desk for your coworkers to see while you're away, a good way to say it is **"退席中"**, which literally means "leaving (your) seat for now," and is a pretty common phrase for a short absence such as having lunch.